# Git .bash_profile Not Working With the Right-click

Tags: git, git-bash, bash

My .bash_profile is not working whenever I right click to a folder and click Git Bash. It works perfectly fine when I open Git Bash with its desktop icon. Here's my .bash_profile:

```
source ~/git-completion.bash

green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

source ~/git-prompt.sh

export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1

export PS1="$green\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \w $ $reset"
```

I tried searching but so far I don't see some answers or at least hints to answer my question.

BTW I got this code from a course in udacity called "Using Git and Github". they have a discussion forum there but I am only enrolled in the free course so I can't access it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: open a git bash by right clicking a folder and enter commad `cd`. Check whether .bash_profile exists in the directory you are taken to.

Comment: @LahiruChandima I tried right-clicking a folder and opened git bash, then enter cd, next I entered ls -a . .bash_profile exists in that particular directory.

Comment: Then try renaming `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc` and reopening git bash

Comment: @LahiruChandima Can you explain to me what happens if I change `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc` exactly? I just want to know what `.bashrc` is (or what the difference between the two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash sources `.bash_profile` if it is opened as a login shell. When you are opening git bash by right clicking on a folder, it is not opened as a login shell so bash does not source `.bash_profile`. The correct file to place your settings is `.bashrc`, which is sourced by bash in interactive non-login shells.

Simply rename `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid redundant content in the bash scripts, you can create your .bashrc with:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Comment: Is this backward, though? My understanding is `.bashrc` is run for non-login shells, and `.bash_profile` is run for login shells. That is, you put into `.bash_profile` the things you only want to run at the top-level shell invocation, and you put into `.bashrc` the things you want to run in easch nested shell. So, you append custom dirs to `PATH` *once* per login session via `.bash_profile`, and then `PATH` doesn't keep redundantly growing in each level of Bash invocation under that (the scripts you invoke, and the scripts they invoke).